# display id of shape in an input type when dropping to drag area and edit shapes in drag area on selecting them

Tags: javascript, html, css

i am experimenting with JavaScript to complete some drag and drop tasks like displaying ids whenever a shape is dropped into a drag area. I cant figure out how to display the ids of the shapes in the table input type of number each time a shape is dropped in the drag space.

here is the JavaScript code

```
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
  }

  function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.id);
  }

  function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();

    var id = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    if (id == "drag1" && ev.target.id == "drag-area") {
      var nodeCopy = document.getElementById(id).cloneNode(true);
      nodeCopy.id = incrementId();
      function incrementId() {
        if (!this.latestId) this.latestId = 1;
        else this.latestId++;
        return this.latestId;
      }
      ev.target.appendChild(nodeCopy);
      var id = document.getElementById(latestId).id;
      //display id on shape
      document.getElementById(latestId).innerHTML = id;
      var value = document.getElementById(latestId).id;
      document.getElementById(latestId).value = value;
      console.log(value);
    }

    if (id == "drag3" && ev.target.id == "drag-area") {
      var nodeCopy = document.getElementById(id).cloneNode(true);
      nodeCopy.id = incrementId();
      function incrementId() {
        if (!this.latestId) this.latestId = 1;
        else this.latestId++;
        return this.latestId;
      }
      ev.target.appendChild(nodeCopy);
      var id = document.getElementById(latestId).id;
      //display id on shape
      document.getElementById(latestId).innerHTML = id;

      var value = document.getElementById(latestId).id;
      document.getElementById(latestId).value = value;
      console.log(value);
    }
  }

  function remove(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    var del = confirm(
      "You are about to DELETE this insert. Do you wish to continue?"
    );

    if (del) {
      var el = document.getElementById(data);
      el.parentNode.removeChild(el);

      console.log("item deleted");
    }
  }
function decreasewidth() {
    var id = document.getElementById(latestId).id;
    var myImg = document.getElementById(id);
    var currWidth = myImg.clientWidth;
    if (currWidth == 50) {
      myImg.style.width = currWidth - 0 + "px";
    } else {
      myImg.style.width = currWidth - 15 + "px";
    }
  }

  function increaseheight() {
    var id = document.getElementById(latestId).id;
    var myImg = document.getElementById(id);
    var currHeight = myImg.clientHeight;
    if (currHeight == 500) {
      myImg.style.height = currHeight + 0 + "px";
    } else {
      myImg.style.height = currHeight + 15 + "px";
    }
  }

  function decreaseheight() {
    var id = document.getElementById(latestId).id;
    var myImg = document.getElementById(id);
    var currHeight = myImg.clientHeight;
    if (currHeight == 50) {
      myImg.style.height = currHeight - 0 + "px";
    } else {
      myImg.style.height = currHeight - 15 + "px";
    }
  }
```

here is the code for the html where the table input is

```
<div class="table-edit">
    Table:<input
    class="table-id"
    ondrop="drop(event)"
    type="number"
    value=""
    />
</div>
```

there is the full html code

```
div class="mains">
  <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->

    <section class="content container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="box box-solid">
            <div class="box-header bg-teal">
              <h3 class="box-title">Tables</h3>
            </div>

            <form action="" method="POST">
              <div class="box-body">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                    <table id="example1" class="table table-striped">
                      <div class="table-area">
                        <div class="row container table-section">
                          <div
                            class="roster-box draggable-shapes col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12"
                            ondrop="remove(event)"
                            ondragover="allowDrop(event)"
                          >
                            <h1
                              class="text-center"
                              style="text-decoration: underline"
                            >
                              tables
                            </h1>
                            <div class="table-area-section">
                              <li>
                                <div
                                  class="circle"
                                  id="drag1"
                                  draggable="true"
                                  ondragstart="drag(event)"
                                  alt="circle"
                                ></div>
                              </li>

                              <li>
                                <div
                                  class="rectangle"
                                  id="drag3"
                                  draggable="true"
                                  ondragstart="drag(event)"
                                ></div>
                              </li>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div
                            class="drag-and-drop col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-12"
                          >
                            <div
                              id="drag-area"
                              class="roster-box text-center drag-section"
                              ondrop="drop(event)"
                              ondragover="allowDrop(event)"
                              onselect="selectImage()"
                            ></div>
                            <div class="edit-section">
                              <li>
                                <div class="table-edit">
                                  Table:<input
                                    class="table-id"
                                    ondrop="drop(event)"
                                    type="number"
                                    value=""
                                  />
                                </div>
                              </li>

                              <li>
                                Width:
                                <div
                                  class="btn-group"
                                  role="group"
                                  aria-label="Third group"
                                >
                                  <button
                                    type="button"
                                    class="btn btn-secondary"
                                    onclick="increasewidth()"
                                  >
                                    +
                                  </button>
                                </div>
                                <div
                                  class="btn-group"
                                  role="group"
                                  aria-label="Third group"
                                >
                                  <button
                                    type="button"
                                    class="btn btn-secondary"
                                    onclick="decreasewidth()"
                                  >
                                    -
                                  </button>
                                </div>
                              </li>
                              <li>
                                Height:
                                <div
                                  class="btn-group"
                                  role="group"
                                  aria-label="Third group"
                                >
                                  <button
                                    type="button"
                                    class="btn btn-secondary"
                                    onclick="increaseheight()"
                                  >
                                    +
                                  </button>
                                </div>
                                <div
                                  class="btn-group"
                                  role="group"
                                  aria-label="Third group"
                                >
                                  <button
                                    type="button"
                                    class="btn btn-secondary"
                                    onclick="decreaseheight()"
                                  >
                                    -
                                  </button>
                                </div>
                              </li>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <!-- /.box-body -->
            </form>
          </div>
          <!-- /. box -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.col -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.row -->
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

styling in addition to bootstrap formats

```
.table-area-section li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px;
}

.drag-section {
  height: 386.5px;
}

.edit-section {
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.edit-section li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.input-group {
  width: 35px;
}

.table-id {
  width: 40px;
}

.draggable-shapes {
  border: 1px solid #c3ccff44;
  height: 677px;
}

.drag-and-drop {
  border: 1px solid #c3ccff44;
}

.table-services > tbody > tr > td,
.table-services > tbody > tr > th,
.table-services > tfoot > tr > td,
.table-services > tfoot > tr > th,
.table-services > thead > tr > td,
.table-services > thead > tr > th {
  padding: 20px;
}

.form-table {
  float: right;
  padding: 20px;
}

.circle {
  background: rgb(168, 168, 168);
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: rgb(168, 168, 168) 6px solid;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}

.rectangle {
  height: 80px;
  background: rgb(168, 168, 168);
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 7%;
  width: 80px;
  border: rgb(168, 168, 168) 6px solid;
}
```

also if there is a way to change the shapes of different shapes on selecting them, I would be happy to receive some idea o how to accomplish that

Comment: I would try and simplify your code a little to show the essence of the problem. Also, it's better only to ask one question at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I have simplified the code quite a bit, but hopefully this does what you are looking for.

I assume that by id's of the shapes, you mean the number at the end of the `id` attribute of the shape? You could parse this out using a regex, but I have went down the simpler solution of storing this number in a data attribute.

```js
function dragover(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("id", ev.target.dataset.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();

  var id = parseInt(ev.dataTransfer.getData("id"), 10);

  inputField.value = id;
}
```

```css
.shapes {
  display: flex;
}

.circle {
  background: rgb(168, 168, 168);
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: rgb(168, 168, 168) 6px solid;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.rectangle {
  margin: 10px;
  height: 80px;
  background: rgb(168, 168, 168);
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 7%;
  width: 80px;
  border: rgb(168, 168, 168) 6px solid;
}

.drop-area {
  padding: 50px;
  border: dotted 2px dimgrey;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-style: italic;
  color: grey;
}

.input {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="shapes">
  <div class="circle" id="drag1" data-id="1" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"></div>
  <div class="rectangle" id="drag3" data-id="3" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"></div>
</div>
<div class="drop-area" ondragover="dragover(event)" ondrop="drop(event)">
  drop zone
</div>
<input id="inputField" class="input" type="number" value="0" />
```

Comment: Actually I think you have simplified too much. Each time I drop a shape in the drop box, the id of the shapes increment thus I was asking how do you display these ids that are incrementing for each shape dropped in the table input

Comment: Ok, that's unfortunate. I would add that explanation to your question to make it clearer that that's what you are trying to do.